# Finding the words from a file which have character 'a' as a last letter

Tags: c++, filestream, getline

```
ifstream input;
string filename="file.txt";
string word;

input.open(filename.c_str());
int len=word.length();

while(getline(input,word)) {

    if(word.at(len-1)='a') {
        cout<<word;
    }

}
```

While I execute it,compiler gives a runtime error I do not understand why ? I want to find the words which have the last character as 'a' thanks

Comment: Since word.length is outside the while loop, you are not actually getting the length of each word you read but just garbage since word is not initialized but you are calling its length method. Print the length of word inside while loop to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int len=word.length();` should be in the loop.

Currently, `len` is `0`.

You also have a typo `=` (assignation) should be `==` (test for equality)

Btw, since C++11, you may use `word.back()`.
And you should check that string is not empty.

Result to:

```
while (getline(input, word)) {
    if (!word.empty() && word.back() == 'a') {
        std::cout << word;
    }
}
```

Comment: No it still gives runtime error.When I want to print all the words I can so I dont think there is a problem with the loop